# Insert data by php on Maria db in forma swe7

Tags: php, mysql, sql, format, mariadb

I formatted a field of a table in my MariaDB in swe7 to host strings from the Swedish alphabet. Yet when I try to enter them in my php script I receive error:

> error INSERT INTO palette (number, address, latitude, longitude, timestamp) VALUES ('7470618', "Östersund Tallbacksvägen", 63.18874861617303, 14.6445424430311, 1440249233) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number='7470618', address="Östersund Tallbacksvägen", latitude=63.18874861617303, longitude=14.6445424430311, timestamp=1440249233 error:Incorrect string value: '\xC3\x96ster...' for column 'address' at row 1

When instead I execute the query directly on the DB, the query is correctly execute and the row inserted. So I think the issue is in the php script, perhaps in the format of its strings, but I do not know how to adjust it.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution was using utf8 and performing the two commands:

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

At that point the encoding in the sql table is irrelevant between utf8 and swe7.

Doing that with swe7 does not work, though.

Answer (score 0):

`C396` is the *utf8* hex encoding for `Ö`

Do you want to use `swe7` because you have data encoded that way?

- `SET NAMES swe7` (or equivalent) when connecting to mysql from your client.
- For the `CHARACTER SET` in your tables, you could use either utf8 or swe7.  With utf8, you allow other languages to be handled.
- If the output is on web pages, be sure to have the appropriate `<meta...charset>` specified.  (I don't know how to spell 'swe7' in that context.)

Or do you have some other reason for wanting swe7?

**Addeda**

Plan A:  Use `swe7` throughout -- SET NAMES, CHARACTER SET, html meta.

Plan B:  `SET NAMES swe7` and a suitable value for html meta charset, but `CHARACTER SET utf8` in the tables.

Either way, the client will see only swe7 encodings.

Comment: When I do it I get error:
INSERT INTO palette (number, address, latitude, longitude, timestamp) VALUES ('7467634', "Fåfängan", 59.5215238601212, 18.49683005654134, 1440837235) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number='7467634', address="Fåfängan", latitude=59.5215238601212, longitude=18.49683005654134, timestamp=1440837235 error:Incorrect string value: '\005CxC3\005CxA5f\005CxC3\005CxA4n...' for column 'address' at row 1
transitType=0 when I try to insert the values in the sql server.

Comment: That was with UTF8, while, if I use swe7, I get no error but the non-latin character are inserted as '?'.

Comment: I need to insert data from a Swedish source in a way that the strings in the db reflect the source.

Comment: The INSERT failure sounds like you had swe7 encoding (as your comment mentioned), but SET NAMES utf8, which disagrees with the encoding.  `SET NAMES swe7` says "the client bytes are encoded swe7; please transcode that and whatever the table wants when INSERTing and SELECTing".

Comment: As answered I managed the issue by setting the mysql character encoding to UTF8 and using those two commend in the php script.